# How to remove wrong path from $(inherited) at the project level?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-warning

I' getting linker warning when I try to build the project:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks'
```

I double checked framework search paths and it looks like $(inherited) contains invalid path.  There's no such folder "Framework" in ".../Xcode.app/.../Library" - there are "GPUTools", "PrivateFrameworks" and "Xcode" folder. Of course this causes this warning to appear. Currently I'm trying to understand how Xcode creates this variable. Any ideas how to fix/remove wrong path from $(inherited)?

**UPDATE** I'm still using Xcode5, and cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look at the project level build settings for the Framework search paths, this is where the target inherits from. Provided you do not manually provide these settings from a config-file, in that case you must fix it in that config-file.

UPDATE: When you use cocoa pods, you should remove the $(inherited) flag and let cocoa pods control this. You could delete everything cocoa pods-generated, except for your pods-file, and remove $(inherited) from your targets configuration, and rerun pod install. This should clear things up for you.

[image: Project settings]

[image: Target settings]

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods was not automatically controlling this field for me. I had to delete the line, go to the framework folder created by Cocoapods, Get Info, then copy-paste the "where" field. Then it worked.